# How to add image with Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Hi here's my Raphael js to create some rectangles on a map svg

```
var rsr = Raphael('map', '600', '600');

var houses = [];

var houses_a = rsr.rect(433.6, 29.4, 100, 100);
houses_a.attr({x: '433.6',y: '29.4',fill: '#FFFFFF',stroke: '#000000',"stroke-width": '5',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data({'id': 'houses_a', 'house': 'House A'});
houses.push(houses_a);
```

i can change the color of the rectangle by

```
houses_a.node.setAttribute('fill', "red");
```

but when try to do

```
houses_a.node.setAttribute('fill', "apple.png");
```

or

```
houses_a.node.setAttribute('src', "apple.png");
```

it won't work.

Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are using element.node.setAttribute rather than element.attr(); There are sometimes reasons, but not sure from the above.,

It depends what you are actually trying to do, it would help if there was a jsfiddle of what you want.

You could use this for example...to create a rect/image

```
var p = Raphael("paper", 800,800);

var img = p.image("http://svg.dabbles.info/tux.png", 10, 10, 300, 300)
           .attr({ "clip-rect": "20,20,300,300" });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianscoding/mp4mc4sc/2/)